# No cernlib on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 20.04

I've upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 but overlooked that there is no CERNLIB in repositories of the newest Ubuntu version. I tried to install manually from *.deb packages but to no success.

Is there a way to install CERNLIB from the Focal Fossa repositories ?

Thanks.
Łukasz

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CERN_Program_Library - "The CERN Program Library or CERNLIB was a set of FORTRAN 77 libraries and modules, ..." ... "Development and support for CERNLIB was discontinued in 2003. "

Comment: cernlib has a LOT of dependencies. If you try to install this manually, I recommend using GDebi for it as it will try to resolve as many dependencies as it can and install the dependencies that are available in 22.04 repos. It will also list the dependencies that are unmet, and you'll probably have to search for these packages and download & install them manually. GDebi is very helpful when you try to install packages that are not in the repos.

Comment: Hmm, looks like just adding the focal repository to /etc/apt/sources.list and apt-getting CERNLIB solves the problem.